# How to get all names of a table column to show if its not part of another table?

Tags: sql

I have a table that has the names of the department, but if a department is not part of the count in the other table then I don't get the department name.

How can I get the names of the departments who are not part of the CSEReduxResponses to display in the output with a 'branchtotalstarsgiven' of 0?

Here are some test data and the query that gets me the count of the departments.

```
create table CSEReduxDepts (csedept_id int, csedept_name varchar(25));

insert into CSEReduxDepts (csedept_id, csedept_name)
values (1,'one'),
(2,'two'),
(3,'three'),
(4,'four');

create table CSEReduxResponses (execoffice_status int, submitterdept int);

insert into CSEReduxResponses (execoffice_status,submitterdept)
values (1,1),
(1,1),
(1,1),
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,2);

------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  submitterdept,csedept_name, COUNT(*) as 'branchtotalstarsgiven'

FROM CSEReduxResponses c
join CSEReduxDepts  d on
c.submitterdept= d.csedept_id
WHERE execoffice_status = 1

GROUP BY execoffice_status, submitterdept, csedept_name
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear, I can't tell what you are saying in your first paragraph. Could you instead show some sample output that you want to see given the sample input you have here?

Comment: well with that data i have i just would like to show 'three' and 'four' to show on output even if there is not data on cseredxreponses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result there are few changes to implement:

- change the `JOIN` from `INNER` to `LEFT/RIGHT`
- change the `WHERE` condition so that it will not remove the department not in `CSEReduxResponses`
- change the `COUNT` so that it'll return 0 when the department is not in `CSEReduxResponses`

the resulting query is
`SELECT submitterdept
     , csedept_name
     , COUNT(execoffice_status) as 'branchtotalstarsgiven'
FROM   CSEReduxDepts d
       LEFT JOIN CSEReduxResponses c on d.csedept_id = c.submitterdept
WHERE  COALESCE(execoffice_status, 1) = 1
GROUP BY execoffice_status, submitterdept, csedept_name`

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c3a3/8)</kbd>

the changed part are in bold, the `COUNT` use execoffice_status as parameter because `COUNT(*)` count every row, but `COUNT(field)` count only the rows that are not null.

Comment: works great, but how would i add a date, like i did in this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4757/1 , it returns like my original query?

Comment: @user3591637 the date column is the `LEFT JOIN`ed table, so you need to `COALESCE` it, or move the condition to the `JOIN`, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4757/3) you can see both, choose the one you like

Answer (score 0):

AS I understood you need names of departements that don't figure in the second table :

```
SELECT csedept_id, csedept_name FROM CSEReduxDepts
WHERE csedept_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct submitterdept FROM CSEReduxResponses)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your inner join to an outer join should work.  Something like this:

```
from CSEReduxDepts d left join SEReduxResponses c 
on c.submitterdept= d.csedept_id 
and execoffice_status = 1
```

Comment: It will work, but `COUNT(*)` will return 1 where the OP want 0